# Is there a term for the "due-ness" of something?

Tags: single-word-requests, time, hypernyms

I have something that can be one of the three states:  *current*, *due*, and *overdue*.

Is there a specific term that describes the set comprised of those states, one that evokes the nature of the states?  For example, *status* is a word that will work, but it doesn't really invoke the specific concept of "due-ness".    I would like to use it instead of *status* in a sentence like:  The status of item X is *current*.

Comment: These are words related to billing a firm or person, apparently.  Usually it's the bill and not an item that's current, due at a particular time, or overdue.

Comment: Can you go with “Bill Status”?

Comment: Less like a bill, more like a library book.   While I prefer a single word, I suppose a compound phrase like "<Thing> Status" would suffice.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: By the by, what's the difference between *current* and *due* please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin asks a good question.  The best way to describe the states are: _current_ is "that period of time where no action is required", _due_ is "that period of time where an action is required but not absolutely necessary", and _overdue_ is "that period of time where an action is both required and necessary".  _Due_ follows _current_, _overdue_ follows _due_.  If the action happens while in _due_ or _overdue_, the state goes back to _current_.

Comment: "Priority", "workflow", "age" are all considerations, depending on domain.

Comment: "Priority" would definitely be the best choice for a work setting (such as an office).